# Add to ggplot with element of different length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot2 and I'm trying to figure out how I can add a line to an already existing plot I created. The original plot, which is the cumulative distribution of a column of data `T1` from a data frame `x`, has about 100,000 elements in it. I have successfully plotted this using ggplot2 and `stat_ecdf()` with the code I posted below. Now I want to add another line using a set of (x,y) coordinates, but when I try this using `geom_line()` I get the error message:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(0, 7.85398574631245e-07, 3.14159923334398e-06,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1001, 100000
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
> set.seed(42)
> x <- data.frame(T1=rchisq(100000,1))
> ps <- seq(0,1,.001)
> ts <- .5*qchisq(ps,1) #50:50 mixture of chi-square (df=1) and 0
> p <- ggplot(x,aes(T1)) + stat_ecdf() + geom_line(aes(ts,ps))
```

That's what produces the error from above. Now here's the code using base graphics that I used to use but that I am now trying to move away from:

```
plot(ecdf(x$T1),xlab="T1",ylab="Cum. Prob.",xlim=c(0,4),ylim=c(0,1),main="Empirical vs. Theoretical Distribution of T1")
lines(ts,ps)
```

I've seen some other posts about adding lines in general, but what I haven't seen is how to add a line when the two originating vectors are not of the same length. (Note: I don't want to just use 100,000 (x,y) coordinates.)

As a bonus, is there an easy way, similar to using `abline`, to add a drop line on a ggplot2 graph?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` deals with `data.frames`, you need to make `ts` and `ps` a `data.frame` then specify this extra `data.frame` in your call to `geom_line`:

```
 set.seed(42)
 x <- data.frame(T1=rchisq(100000,1))
 ps <- seq(0,1,.001)
 ts <- .5*qchisq(ps,1) #50:50 mixture of chi-square (df=1) and 0
 tpdf <- data.frame(ts=ts,ps=ps)
 p <- ggplot(x,aes(T1)) + stat_ecdf() + geom_line(data=tpdf, aes(ts,ps))
```

[image]